# Is it possible to install Windows Server 2019 Standard in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure

I have a question about Windows Server images in Azure. Is there an option in Azure to install Windows Server 2019 Standard. The only options I have been able to install are the Datacenter versions, but I need to be able to install the Standard version.

Comment: And why? Because technically standard has no feature less than datacenter. "I need to" does not sound like you know what you are doing, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Maybe it would be nice if you could expain why you need to install that version, what is your final goal.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can only install Data Centre. There should be no need for installing another version.

Comment: I think the main reason someone would want Standard instead of Datacenter, and the reason I came upon this thread in a search is that licensing with software assurance for Server standard is much less expensive and in the case of the MrLumute, maybe they have previously invested in Server 2019 Standard licensing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there is no real reason to install Standard vs Datacenter and all images from Azure use the Datacenter edtion.

That said, you can always create and upload your own images with whatever you want on them, its a lot of work and I would not recommend it but its technically possible.